# Que significan los datos de las cookies en flask?

Tags: python, flask, cookies

Hola últimamente estoy trabajando con flask y tengo curiosidad sobre las cookies y que datos guardan, por lo que entiendo se separan en 3 y se delimitan por puntos `.` en la primera seccion de la cookie estarian los datos que se guardan dentro de `session` pero quedan 2 parámetros que no se que son y me gustaría saber que datos contienen, ejemplo:

```
session = eyJpbmdyZWRpZW50Ijp7IiBiIjoiYUc5c1lRPT0ifSwibWVhc3VyZW1lbnRzIjp7IiBiIjoiYlhWdVpHOD0ifX0.XzmK0g.SHvAe4Fk4aSEE5fYizxz5GWL2ps
```

esa seria la cookie completa. Y la primera parte seria los datos que se guardan desde el server en base64:

```
echo "eyJpbmdyZWRpZW50Ijp7IiBiIjoiYUc5c1lRPT0ifSwibWVhc3VyZW1lbnRzIjp7IiBiIjoiYlhWdVpHOD0ifX0" | base64 -d
{"ingredient":{" b":"aG9sYQ=="},"measurements":{" b":"bXVuZG8="}}base64: invalid input
```

Aunque faltan los `==` del final por alguna razón. Pero los últimos 2 datos no los entiendo y me gustaría saber que son

```
.XzmK0g
.SHvAe4Fk4aSEE5fYizxz5GWL2ps
```

Creo que uno de los 2 tiene que ver con la fecha pero la verdad no estoy seguro de todas formas les dejo el codigo del servidor de flask

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'tlci0GhK8n5A18K1GTx6KPwfYjuuftWw')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    session['ingredient'] = 'hola'
    session['measurements'] = 'mundo'
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

Flask hace uso del módulo itsDangerous para generar las cookies de sesión firmadas.
Una cookie flask se compone de 2 partes:

```py
   def sign(self, value):
        """Signs the given string and also attaches time information."""
        value = want_bytes(value)
        timestamp = base64_encode(int_to_bytes(self.get_timestamp()))
        sep = want_bytes(self.sep)
        value = value + sep + timestamp
        return value + sep + self.get_signature(value)
```

> def base64_encode(string): 
>     """Base64 encode a string of bytes or text. The resulting bytes are 
>     safe to use in URLs.
>     """
>     string = want_bytes(string)
>     return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(string).rstrip(b"=")

La primera parte es la unión del payload y el timestamp por un punto.

- El payload se codifica en base64 y se elminan los '=' del final.
- El timestamp se convierte a formato big-endian unsigned long long (mediante el módulo struct), se eliminan los '\x00' (función int_to_bytes en flask) y finalmente se codifica en base64.

La segunda parte es la firma del payload.

- La firma se obtiene al procesar el hmac con el algoritmo elegido y codificarlo en base64.

```py
    def get_signature(self, value):
        """Returns the signature for the given value."""
        value = want_bytes(value)
        key = self.derive_key()
        sig = self.algorithm.get_signature(key, value) # el código de esta función está en abajo
        return base64_encode(sig)
```

```py
    def get_signature(self, key, value): #
        mac = hmac.new(key, msg=value, digestmod=self.digest_method)
        return mac.digest()
```

El resultado final es: [(payload)(.)(timestamp)][.][firma]